# How to extract tabular data from a redmine/textile page with AWK in order to declare variables in a shell script?

Tags: bash, awk, redmine, textile

I need to extract data from a page in redmine formatted in textile in order to set variables in a bash script. I want to use AWK to do so. Here is the content of the page:

```
$ cat mypage.redmine
h1. My Awesome page

h2. A section

hello
there

table(metadata).
|TITLE       |An awesome title! |
|VERSIONNUM  |1                 |
|VERSIONDATE |2017-06-16        |
|AUTHOR      |Me!               |

table(otherthing).
|RECORD1     |A value.      |
|RECORD2     |Another value |

h2. Another section

We say things.
```

The information of interest is in the table of class "metadata".

I would like the output to be:

```
TITLE="An awesome title!"
VERSIONNUM="1"
VERSIONDATE="2017-06-16"
AUTHOR="Me!"
```

... so that I can directly call `declare` in my shell script on this output to set variables `TITLE`, `VERSIONNUM`, etc.

Here is what I got so far:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" } { if(NF == 4) print $2 "=" "\"" $3 "\"" }' < mypage.redmine
```

Which renders:

```
TITLE       ="An awesome title! "
VERSIONNUM  ="1                 "
VERSIONDATE ="2017-06-16        "
AUTHOR      ="Me!               "
RECORD1     ="A value.      "
RECORD2     ="Another value "
```

Which is not what I look for... I need the one liner to work only on the table(metadata) and to get rid of trailing spaces.

How can I do so?

**Edit:** I forgot the quotes in the rendering of my attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to address here: selecting the range of lines and picking the proper data from within those lines.

To **extract lines between two patterns** is addressed in [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38972737/1983854) and has an easy solution by using the *Print lines between PAT1 and PAT2 - not including PAT1 and PAT2* solution:

```
awk '/PAT1/{flag=1; next} /PAT2/{flag=0} flag' file
```

In your case, from "table(metadata)" up to a blank line:

```
$ awk '/table\(metadata\)/ {flag=1; next} /^$/ {flag=0} flag' file
|TITLE       |An awesome title! |
|VERSIONNUM  |1                 |
|VERSIONDATE |2017-06-16        |
|AUTHOR      |Me!               |
```

Then, you want to **remove extra characters**. For this, I followed your same approach: set `|` as the FS and print based on that:

```
awk -F"|" '{sub(/[[:space:]]*$/,"",$2);sub(/[[:space:]]*$/,"",$3); printf "%s=\"%s\"\n", $2, $3}' file
```

That is, extract the 2nd and 3rd field, remove all trailing spaces with `sub(/[[:space:]]*$/, "", field)` and finally print a line with the desired format.

Note the use of `[[:space:]]` to match either tabs or spaces. It is the POSIX character class equivalent for `\s`, which you could use with GNU-awk.

**All together**:

```
$ awk -F"|" '/table\(metadata\)/ {flag=1; next} /^$/ {flag=0} flag {sub(/[[:space:]]*$/,"",$2);sub(/[[:space:]]*$/,"",$3); printf "%s=\"%s\"\n", $2, $3}' file
TITLE="An awesome title!"
VERSIONNUM="1"
VERSIONDATE="2017-06-16"
AUTHOR="Me!"
```

Or put it in a script `sc.awk`:

```
BEGIN{FS="|"}
/table\(metadata\)/ {flag=1; next}
/^$/ {flag=0}
flag {
   sub(/[[:space:]]*$/,"",$2);
   sub(/[[:space:]]*$/,"",$3);
   printf "%s=\"%s\"\n", $2, $3
}
```

And execute it with:

```
awk -f sc.awk file
```